# DataTemplated DataGrid not binding correctly? DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate receives null as "item"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So im trying to make a custom styled DataGrid with DataTemplateSelector. I'm new to WPF and binding so I'm probably doing something wrong.

The item object received as parameter to the SelectTemplate function is always null.

I've tried googling this problem but I can't find an answer.

XAML:

```
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!-- Default DataTemplate -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>

            <!-- DataTemplate for Booleans -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanDataTemplate">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>

            <!-- DataTemplate for Arrays -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ArrayDataTemplate">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>

            <local:ValueDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector" 
                   DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}" 
                   BooleanDataTemplate="{StaticResource BooleanDataTemplate}" 
                   ArrayDataTemplate="{StaticResource ArrayDataTemplate}" />

        </Grid.Resources>

        <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding TagListView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

code behind:

```
    public partial class TestView : Window
    {
        public TestView()
        {
            var t = new TestViewModel();
            DataContext = t;
            InitializeComponent();


        }
    }
```

the view model:

```cs
    class TestViewModel
    {

        public TestViewModel()
        {
            generateTestList();
            TagListView = new ListCollectionView(testList);
        }

        private ObservableCollection<TestTag> testList;

        private void generateTestList()
        {
            testList = new ObservableCollection<TestTag>();

            bool b = false;
            testList.Add(new TestTag("bool", (object)b, b.GetType()));

            string s = "...";
            testList.Add(new TestTag("string", (object)s, s.GetType()));

            ushort ui = (ushort)100u;
            testList.Add(new TestTag("uint16", (object)ui, ui.GetType()));

            int[] i_arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            testList.Add(new TestTag("int[]", (object)i_arr, i_arr.GetType()));



        }
        public ListCollectionView TagListView { get; private set; }
}
```

DataTemplateSelector. "item" parameter to SelectTemplate is always null

```cs
public class ValueDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate DefaultDataTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate BooleanDataTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate ArrayDataTemplate { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var tag = item as TestTag;

            Type t = tag.Type;

            if (t == typeof(bool))
                return BooleanDataTemplate;

            if (t == typeof(int[]))
                return ArrayDataTemplate;

            return DefaultDataTemplate;
        }
    }
```

the model

```cs
    class TestTag : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _Name;
        private object _Value;
        public Type Type;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            private set
            {
                _Name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _Value;
            }

            set
            {
                _Value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are just missing a null check on the `SelectTemplate` method:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var tag = item as TestTag;
            if(tag == null)
                return DefaultDataTemplate;
            Type t = tag.Type;
            if (t == typeof(bool))
                return BooleanDataTemplate;
            if (t == typeof(int[]))
                return ArrayDataTemplate;
            return DefaultDataTemplate;
        }
```

You might as well consider some cleaning up to your `TestTag` model class, for instance use generic rather than an Object type, lose the Type property and use the `typeof` whe needed ...

Comment: Thank you so much. The null test does fix the problem; the window now loads and the value column looks as expected.

However the "Name" column is empty, this is a different problem though.

Comment: Regarding the model class; the real ("Tag", not "TestTag") model class is populated by a server who basically publishes (object variable, typeof(variable)) , and I want all "Tags" gathered in the same ObservableCollection. Do you still think generics is a good solution for this and do you have some links I can read to research this problem?

Comment: @jcberg for the Name column, the problem is that simply you set the column Header but you didn't bond it to a specific property in your model, that's an easy fix:
`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />`

Comment: @jcberg for your Tag class I still think that having the type of the variable stored in a property is redundant, Generic or a base class and specific child for each type looks more appropriate here. You can always have all the items in the same collection thanks to Polymorphisme.

Comment: Thanks again, your solution for the Name column was much more elegant than mine. I've also tried improving the model as you suggested (now TestTag<T> which implements ITestTag) and it works really well!